# How do i apply if..else condition?

Tags: java, selenium

My following code take the values which are in format such as 10/12, 2/3, 7/8, it split the values and displays the total of(10+2+7)=19 as Numerator total and (12+3+8) =23 as Denominator total. This loop execute 8 times and there are cases where a single value is there say 47(no split '/' sign in between). Some values are with split and some are without split sign. How do i write it down if..else condition to solve the issue as when ever single values comes, the script gets fail. When there is not split(/) sign, just have to display that value, that will be a single value no need to make a sum with other values.

```
int sumNumerator = 0;
int sumDenominator = 0;  int av=1;
    for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++)
             { 
                // System.out.format("%25s",listOfActualValues.get(j+1).getText());
                 String[] value = listOfActualValues.get(j+av).getText().split("/");

                 for(int i1 =0; i1 < value.length ; i1++) {
                        try {
                            if(value[i1].matches("-?\\d+")){ // any positive or negetive integer or not!
                                //System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(value[i1])+" ");
                                if(i1 == 0) {
                                    sumNumerator += Integer.parseInt(value[i1]);
                                    }

                                else if(i1 == 1){
                                    sumDenominator += Integer.parseInt(value[i1]);

                                            }
                                    }   

                            }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                             System.out.println("Number Format Exception "+e.toString() );
                     }
                    }
                 }



System.out.println("The Numerator Total is: "  + sumNumerator);
System.out.println("The Denominator Total is: " + sumDenominator);
```

I tried  with `String actualValue = listOfActualValues.get(j+1).getText();`

```
if(actualValue.contains('/')){
}
```

but it demands character in place of '/'.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try Pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
 boolean b = m.find();
 if(b){
 your code
 }
 else
 {  }
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but giving an error. for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++)
       { 
   System.out.format("%25s",listOfActualValues.get(j+1).getText());
   String actualValue = listOfActualValues.get(j+1).getText();
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(actualValue);
   boolean b = matcher.find();
   if(b) {
    String[] value = listOfActualValues.get(j+av).getText().split("/");Error at the line, System.out.format("%25s",listOfActualValues.get(j+1).getText());. Error:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2.

Comment: I think its because of my loop. I will check and let you know.